Oracle - Multiple SELECT queries in a single CSV string result without multiple CURSORs
I have an SQL file that will continuously expand and should contain multiple SELECT queries. The goal is to execute multiple SELECT queries simultaneously and get the result back as a single CSV string. I do not want to use separate CURSORs as the script will contain numerous SELECT queries in the future and using many CURSORs in the code is not scalable.
-- (ID_CB, VARCHAR2(15), optional)
-- (X_CB, VARCHAR2(15), optional)
DECLARE
  V_ID_CB VARCHAR2(15) := '{V_ID_CB}';
  V_X_CB VARCHAR2(15) := '{V_X_CB}';
BEGIN
    IF V_ID_CB IS NOT NULL THEN
        OPEN :result_cursor FOR
            SELECT * FROM DEMANDES WHERE ID_CB = V_ID_CB;
    ELSIF V_X_CB IS NOT NULL THEN
        OPEN :result_cursor FOR
            SELECT * FROM SITES;
    END IF;
END;

In the future, I want the script to be able to execute many SELECT queries, and I want to get the result back as a single CSV string without defining a separate CURSOR for each SELECT query.
My question:
Is it possible to execute multiple SELECTs in a single query and get the result as a CSV string?
If so, how could this be achieved without having to define a separate CURSOR for each SELECT?
Thanks in advance for any help.

"Is it possible to execute multiple SELECTs in a single query and get the result as a CSV string?" You can do most things if you try so the answer would be, yes. However, this is one of those things that is probably a bad idea to try and do it as you will create headaches for yourself down the line. Just use multiple SELECTs in multiple cursors.


Is it possible to execute multiple SELECTs in a single query and get the result as a CSV string? If so, how could this be achieved without having to define a separate CURSOR for each SELECT?

If you were going to do this then use UNION ALL:
SELECT 1 AS result_set,
       expression_that_generates_your_csv_string AS csv
FROM   table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, expression_that_generates_your_csv_string FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, expression_that_generates_your_csv_string FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, expression_that_generates_your_csv_string FROM table4

If you want a header row then add extra rows using SELECT ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL containing string literals with the header row:
SELECT 1 AS result_set, 'id,name' AS csv FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, id||',"'||REPLACE(name,'"', '""')||'"' FROM table1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'column1,column2,column3,column4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, col1||','||col2||','||col3||','||col4 FROM table2

However, combining multiple result sets in this way seems like a bad idea.

But what do I do if I have two different tables and these have a different number of columns and therefore the data type of the columns may not match?

@Akin The number of columns does not matter if you are concatenating them all into a single CSV formatted string. SELECT 1 AS result set, id||',"'||REPLACE(name,'"', '""')||'"' AS csv FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT 2, col1||','||col2||','||col3||','||col4 FROM table2 Gives an example where the first table has 2 columns and the second table has 4 columns but they are each concatenated into a single column.

Ok, thanks for pointing this out. Your suggestion with UNION ALL definitely helps me. But do I have to specify the columns? Can't I just say * + ||',"'|| to get back all the columns in the table? If the number of columns doesn't matter anyway, if they are all concatenated into a single CSV formatted string, this should be no problem, right?

@Akin You cannot use *. You need to name all the columns.

Do I also have the option of outputting the column names? Because currently I only get the data records back. Maybe you can use DESCRIBE somehow within the select?

@Akin Yes, just use UNION ALL to add another line with string literals for the column names.

Then the maintenance of my script would be too time-consuming in the future if I needed an additional line for each select in order to output the columns. And if I would only use something like DESCRIBE table, then I would get back all columns instead of those of my returned data cells.
